# Difference between twm and startx

Tags: linux

twm starts the Tab window manager for X desktop. Whereas startx starts the X desktop.

So is there a difference between these two linux commands ?

`twm` and `startx`

Answer (score 0):

You might have a different window manager set to start with `X`. `startx` will run that, while `twm` will always start, well, `twm`.